# How can Unread Emails number be shown right next to Folder Names, as before June 2019?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

[image]

[This forum post](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/313228-outlook-on-the-web-office-365/suggestions/9632826-display-number-of-messages-in-a-folder) outlines the difficulty -

[image]

Comment: File a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: You can post your feedback to Outlook UserVoice :  https://outlook.uservoice.com/